# Get array value after another value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an url that i've put in the variable url

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
```

The url is split on the /

```
url_split = url.split("/")
```

So my array result can be for example:

```
["http:", "", "axces.test", "nl", "categorie", "minibar", ""] 
["http:", "", "axces.test", "nl", "categorie", "minibar", "wand", ""]
```

How can I get the value after the "categorie" value.
So in both cases I want the value "minibar" in an url.

I know I can achieve this with this:

```
var param = url_split[5];
```

But it's possible that "categorie" won't be on the fifth location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for getting the current index of the item `categorie` in your array, then get the next one.

```js
const url = 'http://axces.test/nl/categorie/minibar/wand',
  splitted = url.split('/'),
  categorieIndex = splitted.findIndex((item) => (item === 'categorie')),
  isFound = (categorieIndex > -1);
  
console.log((isFound) ? splitted[categorieIndex + 1] : '"categorie" not found');
```

The snippet above:

- will print `"categorie" not found` if `categorie` is not in `url`.
- will print the next item after `categorie` in `url` if existing.
- will print `undefined` if there is no item after `categorie`.